# VIM: How to remain netrw sidebar window when I open a new tab?

Tags: vim

I have the following in `.vimrc`:

```
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = 25
augroup ProjectDrawer
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * :Vexplore
augroup END
```

It gives me a nice explorer sidebar when I launch vim. But the problem is when I open a new tab with `:tabnew`, it lost the sidebar in the new tab. How can I make `:tabnew` to have the exact same sidebar? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding event is [`:help TabNew`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#TabNew); if you add that to `VimEnter`, you should be good to go:

```
autocmd VimEnter,TabNew * :Vexplore
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work for me; it just opened an empty window split. Delaying the creation helps:

```
autocmd VimEnter * :Vexplore
autocmd TabNew * call feedkeys(":Vexplore\<CR>", 'n')
```

Note that all these instances will be separate from each other; its contents won't be synchronized.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Just one more question. Sometimes, I will see the error msg when I `:qa`, `E37: No write since last change. E162: No write since last change for buffer "NetrwTreeListing 12"`. I have no idea when and how this happened. Do you know how I can prevent this error message? Cheers.

Comment: The risky thing about `feedkeys()` is that it may interfere with they keys typed by the user. Your case sounds like some keys modified the netrw buffer somehow.

Comment: The [NERDTree plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) may be an alternative worth looking into. One of its features: _You can have a separate NERD tree for each tab, share trees across tabs, or a mix of both._

Comment: What to do to avoid modifying the netrw buffer? I didn't do anything except browsing the directory actually. thanks.